# Collectors.groupingBy for optional field's inner field

Tags: java, java-stream

I'd like to map a stream `Stream<Car>` to the map like `Map<String, List<Car<StudentInGroup>>>` where `Car` class is like this:

```
public class Car<T> {
    Optional<T> studentInGroup;
    public Car()
    {  
    }

    public Optional<T> getStudentInGroup() {
        return studentInGroup;
    }

    public void setStudentInGroup(T studentInGroup) {
        this.studentInGroup=Optional.of(studentInGroup);
    }
}
```

and `StudentInGroup` is like

```
public class StudentInGroup {
    private String name;
    private boolean isGirl;
    private int age;
}
```

so, i'd like to build a map based on `StudenInGroup`'s name field, it the `Optional<StudentInGroup>` inside the Car is not `Optional.empty()` while I'd like to substitute it with "none" if in the specific cat the studentIngroup field is equal to `Optional.empty()`.

```
Map<String, List<Car<StudentInGroup>>> stringStudentInGroupMap38= studentInGroupStreamSupplier.get().map((StudentInGroup studentInGroup)->{Car<StudentInGroup> car=new Car<StudentInGroup>();car.setStudentInGroup(studentInGroup);return car;}).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(car->car.getStudentInGroup().orElseGet(... do something with student there).getName())
```

The possible solution is to create the "none containing StudentInGroup" whose getName will return the desired data, while this doesn't looks like the right approach. however< I haven't found any way to preserve the original `Stream<Car>` without mapping it to some other Streams and force the grouping on Car.StudentInGroup.Name or "none" if `Optional<StudenInGroup>` is empty. Any suggestions to code it clear and readable are welcomed!

Comment: `Stream<Car>` is a raw type. Shouldn't it be `Stream<Car<StudentInGroup>>`?

Comment: If so, just do `cars.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(car -> car.getStudentInGroup().map(s -> s.getName()).orElse("none")))`

Comment: @Deadpool filter wouldn't work as I'd like the empty optionals to be included to the map too

Comment: @shmosel good idea

Comment: @shmosel please post you answer as the official answer, it worked for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `groupingBy()` collector and map the `Optional` to get the key:

```
Map<String, List<Car<StudentInGroup>>> byName = cars.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                car -> car.getStudentInGroup()
                        .map(s -> s.getName())
                        .orElse("none")))
```